# commands of catkin tools giving errors

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently I installed catkin tools. I have ros (melodic) installed on my system (Ubuntu 18.04). The problem is that I can use catkin_init_workspace, but not catkin init. Using catkin_init or any of the commands of catkin tools gives me an error that asyncio
is missing. So I installed asyncio using pip, but now I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/comp/.local/bin/catkin", line 11, in <module>
load_entry_point('catkin-tools==0.4.5', 'console_scripts', 'catkin')()
File "/home/comp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/home/comp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2852, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "/home/comp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2443, in load
return self.resolve()
File "/home/comp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
File "/home/comp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_tools/commands/catkin.py", line 28, in <module>
from catkin_tools.common import is_tty
File "/home/comp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_tools/common.py", line 24, in <module>
import asyncio
File "/home/comp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/asyncio/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
from . import selectors
File "/home/comp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/asyncio/selectors.py", line 39
"{!r}".format(fileobj)) from None
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT :**

I just made a directory with a src directory in it  and ran :

```
catkin init
```

I get the above error. However catkin_init_workspace worked fine. If needed, these are the instructions I followed to install catkin tools -

https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html

This is how I installed catkin tools -

$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu `lsb_release -sc` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

$ wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install python-catkin-tools

This is the command I used to install asyncio:

```
pip install asyncio
```

**EDIT 2:**

I tried to install catkin tools from source (from the same website as earlier). I am still getting syntax errors, but different ones...

Commands I used:

$ git clone https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools.git

$ cd catkin_tools

$ pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade

$ sudo python setup.py install --record install_manifest.txt

The first three commands work fine, the fourth one (sudo python setup.py install ...) gives these errors:

```
sudo python setup.py install --record install_manifest.txt
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_tools/execution/executor.py to executor.pyc
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_tools/execution/executor.py", line 73
yield from lock
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

running install_data
running install_egg_info
running egg_info
writing requirements to catkin_tools.egg-info/requires.txt
writing catkin_tools.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to catkin_tools.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to catkin_tools.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to catkin_tools.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'catkin_tools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'catkin_tools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
removing '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_tools-0.4.5-py2.7.egg-info' (and everything under it)
Copying catkin_tools.egg-info to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_tools-0.4.5-py2.7.egg-info
running install_scripts
Installing catkin script to /usr/local/bin
writing list of installed files to 'install_manifest.txt'
```

Changing permissions of /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_tools/ .... I am not posting these permissions as they are too big.. Example of these changing permissions (I am posting one of the lines):

```
changing permissions of /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_tools/spaces/__init__.pyc to 644
```

Then after these changes, I get this error:

```
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/catkin_tools/execution/executor.pyc'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353893/commands-of-catkin-tools-giving-errors/) by [TheRoot](https://answers.ros.org/users/55445/theroot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2020-06-02

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2020-06-02**:
post your code, please

**Comment by [TheRoot](https://answers.ros.org/users/55445/theroot/) on 2020-06-02**:
I have posted what I have done @Procópio

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-03**:\

> ```
> File "/home/comp/.local/bin/catkin"
> ```

how did you install `catkin_tools`? The file path in your traceback suggests you used `pip`.

Could you explain why you used `pip`?

**Comment by [TheRoot](https://answers.ros.org/users/55445/theroot/) on 2020-06-03**:
So, I have updated exactly how I installed catkin tools...I don't think if I have used pip...please pardon me as I am a beginner..@gvdhoorn

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-03**:\

> I have ros (melodic) installed on my system (Ubuntu 18.04).

Assuming you are using the system Python 2.x, why don't you use:

```
sudo apt install python-catkin-tools?
```

I would recommend to clean up the mess created by `sudo python setup.py install` (ie: uninstall it).

If you *must* install things from sources, use `pip` to do it, so you have an easy way to uninstall.

And you still haven't told us *why* you installed things from source.

**Comment by [TheRoot](https://answers.ros.org/users/55445/theroot/) on 2020-06-03**:
It said that catkin tools was in beta...so I thought installing it from source might resolve the issue for me...I ran sudo apt-get remove python setup.py and installed catkin tools using sudo apt install python-catkin-tools  .... but still I am getting this issue @gvdhoorn

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-03**:\

> It said that catkin tools was in beta...so I thought installing it from source might resolve the issue for me

I would strongly recommend to avoid building things from source, *unless* you have an absolute necessity.

Also: if you do, use tools which isolate these source builds (ie: don't run `sudo [..] install`), because that will contaminate your system with all sorts of files, and you don't know where they go.

> but still I am getting this issue

Did you clean out everything which was installed as part of your initial attempts from `/usr/local`? Those paths also appear in the traceback you show. You'll have to clean all that up. And `/home/comp/.local`.

I've just ran `docker run -ti --rm ros:melodic` and then `apt update && apt install python-catkin-tools`. Invoking `catkin` (ie: the base command) or `catkin config` on a workspace works for me. No tracebacks.

At this point, assuming you have a standard Bionic & Melodic installation, `catkin_tools` should still work on Bionic.

**Comment by [JustinBlack02](https://answers.ros.org/users/26403/justinblack02/) on 2020-06-03**:
@gvdhoorn, interesting, I'm not getting the same results even after pulling the latest docker image.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-04**:
If you can show us the exact commands you used, that would be interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `master` branch doesn't support Python 2 anymore.

For Python 2 compatible code you should use the `0.6.x` branch.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-04**:
Isn't the real question here why the OP doesn't use `sudo apt install python-catkin-tools` on Melodic?